# How can i add a global validation for a ASP.NET Core web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Lets say, we have got multiple models with properties like (email, name, address).
In addition to these as required fields, email accepts @ while address accepts # & etc..

So I wanted to have a application level validation, which will restrict all the special characters. And for properties with some exception, will write an exception.

I am new to web api, and would like this to implement somewhere at startup.cs 
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: did my answer helped you  ?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use FluentValidation. [Click Here](https://fluentvalidation.net/)

usage:

```
public class MyValidator: AbstractValidator<Customer> {
  public CustomerValidator() {
    RuleFor(x => x.Surname).NotEmpty();
    RuleFor(x => x.Forename).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Please specify a first name");
    RuleFor(x => x.Discount).NotEqual(0).When(x => x.HasDiscount);
    RuleFor(x => x.Address).Length(20, 250);
    RuleFor(x => x.Postcode).Must(BeAValidPostcode).WithMessage("Please specify a valid postcode");
  }



  private bool BeAValidPostcode(string postcode) {
    // custom postcode validating logic goes here
  }
}
```

In your case you can just replace `AbstractValidator<Customer>` with a base type that is derived `AbstractValidator<Customer>` from that on,you can do what ever validations you need on your base DTO.
**although i think there is some apis on ur application takes no params.**

for me, its the most effective and clean way.

Hope that helped...